# Using attributes to intercept then reissue method calls

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I'd like create an attribute that when placed on a method it:

1. Checks a condition
2. If true, execute the method, if false, it executes an async method which calls the original method on callback.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing an attribute on a method doesn't affect the method itself. You would have to write code that does this transformation, then use something like PostSharp to apply the transformation to every method marked with the attribute after you have compiled it.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Postsharp. Attributes dont change code. A runtime needs to evalaute them. What you want to go into is aspect oriented programming. Have a look at Postsharp.