# What would be the most efficient way to intercept and ignore a method call on a certain condition?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, static-methods, custom-attributes

I have a class `Logger` with a number of static methods for various user activity logging. Something like:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void FileDownload(int fileId, int userId) 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    // ... and a number of similar additional methods
}
```

So what I've come to now is that I want to ignore logging the activity for users of a certain role.

The idea I had, to avoid rewriting a lot of code and for the purpose of DRY, was to implement a custom attribute that I can use on the `Logger` class, which will, for every method call, verify if the user is in a certain role, and in that case I want to ignore the method call altogether.

The problem I can't wrap my head around is how to intercept and abort the method-call within my attribute.

Is it possible, or is there some other more efficient way to intercept a method call and ignore it if a certain condition is true?

Comment: No, C# provides no mechanism for ad-hoc method interception a la AOP.

Comment: This looks like a very similar question/answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502134/using-attributes-to-intercept-then-reissue-method-calls

Comment: @gymbrall It does indeed, don't know how I missed it, been searching around SO for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this efficiently and `DRY` is to change those methods from `static` to instance methods, then inherit from class `Logger` and override its methods to do nothing.

Your `Logger` class will now look like this:

```
public class Logger
{
    public virtual void FileDownload(int fileId, int userId) 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    // ... and a number of similar additional methods
}
```

And the subclass will look like this:

```
public class IdleLogger : Logger
{
    public override void FileDownload(int fileId, int userId) 
    {
        // Do NOTHING
    }
    // ... and a number of similar additional methods
}
```

Then you can say:

```
var myLogger =  IsUserInNoLoggingRole  ? new IdleLogger() : new Logger();
```

...and you are done! Simple, efficient, DRY and elegant.

Comment: +1: setting logger per-request based on user. May be useful to cache in HttpContext.Current.Items or use dependency injection container that can be configured to return different instances per-request.

Comment: I like this approach. I guess I could instantiate the logger and keep it in my SecurityContext for simplicity.

Comment: in multi user environment which is the case here, will this approach not create more (than required) instances of logger? or have I missed the obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to simply check before actually logging anything?

```
public static class Logger
{
 public void LogSensetiveInformation(string message)
 {
  if (!AllowedLogging(HttpContext.Current)
  {
    return;
  }

  LogMessage(message);// write message to some storage

 }
 public void Log(string message)
 {
  LogMessage(message);// write message to some storage
 }
}
```

This way you don't need to annotate code in any special way (which probably not possible anyway since the same methods are likely to be used by all kinds of users).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The reason I wanted to use an attribute or similar was so that I didn't have to do the check within every method.

Comment: You only need to add checks to your logger itself, you regular code will stay the same. Also I like Diego's answer more as more generic.

Answer (score 0):

in general your logging should be complete, it is upto the reporting application that would need to decide to show the activity based on user types. that said,  however (and I am sure you have valid reason to do "if then else") this can be achieved by creating a common logging method (logMessage)

```
int t = User.LogRequired? logMessage(<parameters here>) : 0;
```